# Use value outside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

```
public class randomdemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int [] varArray = new int[rand.nextInt(10)];

        System.out.println(varArray.length);
        int d = rand.nextInt(1999)-1000;
        for (int i=0;i<varArray.length;i++)
        {
            varArray[i]= rand.nextInt(1999)-1000;
            System.out.println(varArray[i]);

            if(d==varArray[i])
            {
                System.out.println(d);      
                System.out.println(i+1);
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println(d);
                System.out.println(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problems in code:

It executes the if-else statement multiple times and displays the if-else output multiple times since it is in for loop.
The code should execute the if-else statement only once but the rest of the for loop should be executed multiple times.
Since the if statement is using value of `varArray[i]` I cannot exclude the code from the for loop.
When `break` statement is used it is terminating the `for` loop. and the complete output is not shown.

output: currently

7
-710
-249
0
-693
-249
0
172
-249
0
-488
-249
0
-48
-249
0
955
-249
0
869
-249
0

As you can see the length of array is 7
it displays array element then value of variable d and value 0 in a loop.

expected output:

7
-710
-693
172
-488
-48
955
869
-249
0

the output of array with 7 elements should be 7 array values followed by variable d and 0.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the if/else into another conditional block that only runs the first time through the loop (like when `i == 0`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a value outside for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629841/how-to-use-a-value-outside-for-loop)

Comment: And don't ask the same question twice, try to follow up on your previous question instead.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  Provide a sample of the output you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

Please identify the exact scenario in which you want to execute the if-else and make changes in the existing if-else condition so that it executes only once in the loop. Or you can wrap the existing if-else inside other if-else,for which the condition can be the scenario in which you have to execute the inner if-else.

For eg: Let the scenario is like only for a particular value of i(say when i=10) you want to execute the loop.Please modify the code as below.

```
if(i==10){
 if(d==varArray[i])
            {
                System.out.println(d);      
                System.out.println(i+1);
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println(d);
                System.out.println(0);
            }

}
```

Comment: the value i is randomly generated.

Comment: the value of i is randomly generated in the program. cannot specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can set a boolean flag to track execution of your if else code .. see code below.

```
    boolean flag = false;  // flag to track the if else

    System.out.println(varArray.length);
    int d = rand.nextInt(1999)-1000;
    for (int i=0;i<varArray.length;i++)
    { 
      ...
       if(!flag){
        if(d==varArray[i])
        {
            flag =true;
            System.out.println(d);      
            System.out.println(i+1);
        }
        else
        { 
             flag =true;
            System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println(0);
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class randomdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] varArray = new int[rand.nextInt(10)];

        System.out.println(varArray.length);
        int d = rand.nextInt(1999) - 1000;
        int foundIdx = -1; // mark index if you find one!
        for (int i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
            varArray[i] = rand.nextInt(1999) - 1000;
            System.out.println(varArray[i]);

            if (d == varArray[i]) {
                foundIdx = i + 1; // only the last match is saved
            }
        }
        if (foundIdx != -1) {
            System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println(foundIdx);
        } else {
            System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
}
```